# SQL - Delete and subquery

Tags: sql, relational-database, embedded-sql

The following is a sql query which I wrote to delete all records in the placement table where the `placement.op_number` = a list of returned records.

The subquery works fine alone and returns only the `OP_NUMBER` column (with two rows).

The error I get is:

> At most one record can be returned from the Sub-Query

```
DELETE
FROM PLACEMENT
WHERE PLACEMENT.OP_NUMBER = (SELECT OP_NUMBER
                             FROM Opening
                             WHERE opening.qual_code = "SEC-45");
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `IN` instead of equals:

```
delete
from PLACEMENT
where PLACEMENT.OP_NUMBER in (
        select OP_NUMBER
        from Opening
        where opening.qual_code = "SEC-45"
        );
```

Comment: I think `IN` can fail if there are null OP_NUMBER records in opening table

Comment: Thanks Mate - Will Accept As Soon as i am able to !

Answer (score 1):

```
DELETE
FROM PLACEMENT
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT OP_NUMBER FROM Opening
               WHERE opening.qual_code = "SEC-45" 
              AND OP_NUMBER = PLACEMENT.OP_NUMBER);
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently you are comparing PLACEMENT.OP_NUMBER to a recordset - an Int vs a recordset.
You will want to use the IN keyword in order to compare a condition with multiple values

Your new query should look like this -

```
DELETE
FROM PLACEMENT
WHERE PLACEMENT.OP_NUMBER IN (SELECT OP_NUMBER
                             FROM Opening
                             WHERE opening.qual_code = "SEC-45");
```